# MongoDB findAndModify SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

`db.RO_DECLINE_DATA.findAndModify("query":{"$or":[{"emailMessageID":345544985},{"textMessageID":345544985}]},"update":{"$set":{"emailMessageStatus":"FAILED","emailSentDate":null}});`

`db.INBOX_COLLECTION.aggregate("pipeline":[{"$match":{"dealerID":1224,"dealerDepartmentID":3994,"dealerAssociateID":{"$in":[68638,68891]}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$customerID"}}]);`

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with these queries?

Error
`2021-07-14T01:28:06.106+0530 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list :`

i don't think any ')' is missing

Comment: You forgot the curly brackets around your argument object. `findAndModify({"query": ...`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev after adding curly brackets query is this ```db.RO_DECLINE_DATA.findAndModify({"query":{"$or":[{"emailMessageID":345543479},{"textMessageID":345543479}]}},{"update":{"$set":{"emailMessageStatus":"FAILED","emailSentDate":null}}});```
but I have new error now
```2021-07-14T01:49:13.778+0530 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "code" : 9,
        "errmsg" : "Either an update or remove=true must be specified",
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1626207553, 1)
} ```

Comment: This wrapping is off. Review the syntax in the docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/